# Conflict between data.table, readr, and dplyr?

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I'm experiencing an apparent conflict between the data.table (v 1.9.4), dplyr (v 0.4.1), and readr (v 0.1.1) packages. I'm working in RStudio (Version 0.98.1103) and R Version 3.2.0 on Windows 7.

The issue arises when loading the data.table into R with this code:

```
DT <- as.data.table(
      read_csv("my_file.csv", 
      col_types = list(Date1 = col_date(format = "%Y/%m/%d"), 
                       Date2 = col_date(format = "%Y/%m/%d")))
      )
```

The file appears to load fine and str(DT) reports the table as:

```
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’, ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':
```

Yet, when trying to assign a value using the := operator I get this error message:

```
Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, 
once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").
```

So it doesn't seem to be recognizing it as a data.table.

Likewise, I get this error when attempting to use the .N function in j to count records by my year fields:

```
Error in `[.tbl_df`(DT, , .N, keyby = Date1) : unused argument (keyby = Date1)
```

I'm not a very sophisticated user, so I could be missing something simple. I suspected readr because it is the newest. Yet it takes readr plus dplyr to get the error. If I just use data.table and readr without loading dplyr, then there is no issue. And if I load the data into R without readr, even if readr is loaded, then data.table and dplyr work fine together.

I can obviously workaround the issue but wanted to report it. I like data.table's syntax and would normally use fread to read in the data. I was using readr here, so as to learn it, yet also because of its ability to work with date and time fields. I use dplyr mainly for its ability to work with databases.

Lastly, I just picked up this project again after leaving it untouched for a couple of weeks. I do not remember this issue arising before yet have not tracked which packages have updated since that time.

Comment: This was taken care of in `data.table v 1.9.5` - https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1078

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I appreciate it. I did try and update all three packages, and looked around github some, but apparently not hard enough. . . Cheers.

Comment: Thank you again for the help. I'd say it was a bit premature to close this however. I can see closing it when data.table v 1.9.5 becomes available through CRAN. Not everyone will download it before then. Because I lack admin rights on my work computer, I'm one such person. I'm still working with v 1.9.4.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you to Arun for pointing out this issue was known, has to do with the tbl_df class, and will be fixed with the update to v 1.9.5 of data.table.